# Paypal with IPN in PHP not working in new Beta developer sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

i had integrated PayPal with IPN in PHP, before new Paypal development it redirect to sandbox and successfully login with Sandbox it allow to test payment, now its redirect to beta developer site and not going to test the payment,

following is PHP Paypal class i used,

```
class paypal_class {
var $error; // holds the error encountered
var $ipn_log; // log IPN results
var $ipn_log_file; // filename of the IPN log
var $ipn_response; // holds the IPN response from PayPal
var $ipn_data = array(); // contains the POST values for IPN
var $fields = array(); // holds the fields to submit to PayPal
function paypal_class() {
// constructor.
$this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$this->error = '';
$this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
$this->ipn_log = true;
$this->ipn_response = '';
$this->add_field('rm','2'); // Return method = POST
$this->add_field('cmd','_xclick');
}
function add_field($field, $value) {
// adds a key=>value pair to the fields array
$this->fields["$field"] = $value;
}
function submit_paypal_post() {
// generates an HTML page consisting of
// a form with hidden elements which is submitted to PayPal
echo "<html>\n";
echo "<head><title>Processing...</title></head>\n";
echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.....</h2></center>\n";
echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";
foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
}
echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
echo "</body></html>\n";
}
function validate_ipn() {
// parse the paypal URL
$url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);
// generate the post string from the _POST vars
$post_string = '';
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) {
$this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
$post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode (stripslashes ($value)).'&';
}
$post_string .= "cmd=_notify-validate";
// open the connection to paypal
$fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);
if(!$fp) {
// Print the error if not able to open the connection.
$this->error = "Error no. $errnum: $errstr";
$this->log_ipn_results(false);
return false;
} else {
// Post data back to paypal
fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");
// loop through the response from the server and append to variable
while(!feof($fp)) {
$this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
}
fclose($fp); // close connection
}
if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {
// Valid IPN.
$this->log_ipn_results(true);
return true;
} else {
// Invalid IPN.
$this->error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
$this->log_ipn_results(false);
return false;
}
}
function log_ipn_results($success) {
if (!$this->ipn_log) return;
// Timestamp
$text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - ';
// Success or failure
if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->error."\n";
// Log the POST variables
$text .= "IPN POST Values from Paypal:\n";
foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
$text .= "$key=$value, ";
}
// response from the paypal server
$text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;
// Write to log
$fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n");
fclose($fp); // close file
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Try clearing your cookies and cache prior to opening up the browser and going to developer.paypal.com

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has made some changes. Now create an account on https://developer.paypal.com/ I used same email id as I was using with sandbox. After the registration process login on https://developer.paypal.com/
Click on Applications
Click on Sandbox accounts
To import your previous sandbox data click on "Import data" link OR create a new test account by clicking on "Create Account" button

Paypal creates a default merchant account at the time of signup.
To see any of sandbox account just click on it. New options would be available. Browse the functionality of these.

Here you are ready to use your sandbox details again